# How do I use Weka's MLP output prediction model in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, weka

I'm trying to do prediction in Matlab using the output of Weka's single layer MLP.
In my case I have a single layer with 100 nodes and 200 features.
I'm running Weka 3.7.10, and the options for weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron is
-L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a

Node 0 is Linear in my case, not Sigmoid.
Node 1-100 are all Sigmoid. I didn't use the -C or -I option, so by default Weka normalizes the data.

When I try to compute the predicted value in Matlab, I don't get the same value as on Weka.
In the following code:

- featvals is my feature vector (stored as 200 rows)

  featweightsall is the 200 feature weights from each of the 100 nodes that Weka provides.

  nodeweights is the 100 nodeweights that Weka provides.

  nodethresh is the 101 thresholds that Weka provides (rows 2-101 contain the threshold for Nodes 1-100, and row 1 contains the threshold for Node 0).

```
featvalsnorm = interp1([min(featvals) max(featvals)],[-1 1],featvals,'linear');
featvalsnorm2 = (featvals - min(featvals))/(max(featvals)-min(featvals));
for j = 1:100
    featweights = featweightsall(  ((j-1)*200+1):(j*200));
    x = sum(featvalsnorm.*featweights) + nodethresh(j+1);
    nodenorm(j) = 1/(1+exp(-x));
end
predvalnorm = sum(nodenorm.*nodeweights)+nodethresh(1);
predval = interp1([-1 1],[min(featvals) max(featvals)],predvalnorm,'linear');
```

What's wrong with the code? Am I supposed to un-normalize in the loop, or apply the
sigmoid to Node 0? I've tried many of these combinations, and nothing's working. Any help would be appreciated!